# Duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 using Google Sign-In SDK 4.0.1

Tags: ios, xcode, google-signin

I was stuck with this error from the past 2 days. Please Ignore if this question already exists as I don't found any solution I am posting this.

In my project I have integrated google maps sdk that is working fine. Presently i am using o-Auth request for gmail sign in, Now I want to implement Google Sign-In SDK 4.0.1.

My project was building with out errors before copying it. I followed the steps that are given in this [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk/) to copy sdk to my app. I was getting this error

```
ld: 108 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**I use the following solutions still can't fix it**:

1. Build Options -> Enable Bitcode -> set "No".
2. Remove -ObjC from Other Linker Flags.
3. project Target -> Build phases -> compile sources, ckeck no
   duplicate files.
4. Make sure I haven't #imported a .m file.

   Deploytarget is 6.0

Checked all solutions but didn't worked me ...Can any one suggest me how to fix this?

Comment: Add the ObjC linker flag to the app target's build settings:
Other Linker Flags: $(OTHER_LDFLAGS) -ObjC

Comment: check for any duplicate files you added in your project

Comment: @YogendraGirase Yes I have added it. Still getting the same

Comment: @Wolverine I can run the project with out errors befor adding this sdk. After adding it simply i am unable to run project.

Comment: Then is should be problem of integrating it properly. remove the file and again follow the steps.

Comment: I have added it multiple times.still that was not fixed. Tried by deleting derived data too but of no use

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced same issue in implementing Google Sign-In SDK. I have not found any solution to it. But to solve this issue follow these steps.

- Either you should use `CocoaPods` and follow the documentation you will not get these error.
- If you are not using `CocoaPods`, then in that case follow the 'Demo Project' that comes with Google Sign-In SDK. Use all the frameworks that are used in this 'Demo Project' and also add the required libraries as in project.
- Don't forget to add linker flag.

Note : I know this is not the solution, but i had to  follow the 'Demo Project' to solve this issue.

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SSReadingList", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(please_link_SafariServices.framework_.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) was getting this error

Comment: I think you are missing SafariServices.framework add it.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply ...I have added safari frameworks too still no use

Answer (score 0):

For me, this error happened because somehow CocoaPods appears to have duplicated a GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.m file, creating a GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch 2.m file and including it in the project.

`pod update` did not resolve. I manually deleted the file and the issue went away. After another `pod update`, the issue did not reappear.